# Comment exprimer « with source tuning » (à propos d'un logiciel sous lequel on évalue la performance d'un processeur) ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, informatique, formulation

Dans un graphique on compare la performance de processeurs sous un logiciel (*Weather Research and Forecasting Model*) et on oppose « out of the box » à « w/ src tuning » (*with source tuning*). À l'évidence c'est le *source* du [code source](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8391804). S'agit-il de *(avec) [paramétrage](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tuning#Translations) des sources* ou autrement et peut-on sommairement l'étayer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paramétrage ne concernerait qu'une modification des paramètres passés au programme alors que *src tuning* sous-entend que le code lui-même est modifié.

On pourra donc plutôt dire :

> avec ajustement du code source.

ou mieux :

> avec optimisation du code source.

Il peut aussi y avoir un *tuning* qui consiste à adapter le compilateur au code à compiler ou à utiliser des options de compilation spécifiques pour générer un exécutable plus performant. On parle alors d'options d'optimisation.

Comment: J’ai toujours entendu le second exemple pour l’optimisation par rapport à l’OS, et *adaptation* remplacer *ajustement* quand il s’agit du logiciel.

Comment: @cl-rSOrendezconfianceenFL Oui, *ajustement* n'est pas très courant dans ce contexte, je devrais peut-être ne laisser qu'optimisation. J'entend plus souvent *adaptation* pour évoquer le portage d'un programme pour qu'il puisse se compiler et/ou s'exécuter dans un environnement cible différent de celui pour lequel il a été conçu (OS, bibliothèques, etc.) plutôt que pour du *tuning*, c'est à dire, des modifications ayant pour but de meilleures performances ou une moindre utilisation de ressources.

Comment: S’il s’agit du paramétrage comme le suggère la question « avec *réglage* des paramètres du code source »

Comment: Je ne pense pas nécessairement que produire la source du graphique en question aide vraiment mais [voici](https://youtu.be/eXhlDt2SD8o?t=576) au cas où... Mais considérant tous ces termes et leurs nuances, si tu avais eu à en choisir un dans cette vidéo/ce graphique, lequel aurais-tu sélectionné ?

Comment: @cl-rSOrendezconfianceenFL N'hésite pas à rédiger une réponse complémentaire au besoin !

Comment: Après avoir visionné la video, il s'agit très probablement d'optimisation du code source en question (WRF 3.8.1) pour l'adapter aux caractéristiques du processeur et de l'architecture matérielle utilisée, bien qu'aucun détail ne soit vraiment donné. C'est du marketing, pas une présentation technique. On peut quand même supposer que, les tests s'appuyant sur une version assez ancienne (2016), ils ont beaucoup travaillé sur l'optimisation de son code.